# Duplicate an elasticsearch index from local network to production server

Tags: elasticsearch

I index thousands of pdfs in an elasticsearch index inside my local network and I want to replicate it on a production server with a public IP.

I don't store pdfs inside elasticsearch index.

What is the best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet would be [snapshot restore](http://blog.qbox.io/topic/snapshot).
As both of them are incremental , it fits the bill.

Personally ,  i would go for a AWS repository , take snapshot on it on a periodic interval or whenever i am done indexing a bunch of documents and then restore it from the production side.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-snapshots.html).

Comment: Snapshot/restore is definitively the good solution. But cloud repository such AWS is not an option for me !